# Set D3 line stroke according to deviation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is a sample of my data:

```
x   var min max
045 53.4    55  60
046 52.2    51  60
047 52.7    52  60
048 53.1    53  60
049 49.0    54  60
050 50.4    55  60
051 51.1    56  60
052 52.3    51  60
053 54.6    52  60
054 55.1    53  60
055 51.5    53  60
056 53.6    54  60
057 52.3    55  60
```

I want to plot var against x but the color of the line should be black if var is inside [min,max] and red if it is outside.

Plotting the line if OK but the I cannot change the color. I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="lib/vendor/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.var); })
    .style('stroke', function(d) { return (d.var>d.min && d.var<d.max) ? 0 : d3.rgb('#EE0000'); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("smidata.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain([data[0].x, data[data.length - 1].x]);
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.var; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Measurement");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
</body>
```

But style is not a function here.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I figured how to do it thanks to the link provided. Still very rough though. If a more simple solution exist, it is welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
   body {
      margin: auto;
      width: 960px;
   }

   text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
   }
   svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20em;
   }
   g.axis line,
   g.axis path {
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      fill: none;
      stroke: black;
   }
   g.plot line {
      stroke-width: 2;
   }
</style>

<body>
   <script src="lib/vendor/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      function update(data) {
         lines = lines.data(data);

         xScale.domain([data[0].x, data[data.length - 1].x]);
         var inter = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.var; });
         yScale.domain([0,100]);

         lines.enter().append("line");
         lines.each(function (d, i) {
               var elem = data[i];
               //plotting value for current point      

               //find next point
               var nextElem;
               if (i+1 == data.length) {
                  // there is no next value,
                  // so repeat this point as the end of line
                  //(line will have zero length)
                  nextElem = elem;
               } else {
                  nextElem = data[i+1];
               }
               d3.select(this)
                  .attr( //set coordinates:
                     {
                        x1: xScale(elem.x),
                        y1: yScale(elem.var),
                        x2: xScale(nextElem.x),
                        y2: yScale(nextElem.var)
                     }
               )
               //Set styles for individual line segments
               .style("stroke", (elem.var > elem.min && elem.var < elem.max) ? "black" : "red");
         });
      }

       //*** INITIALIZATION ***//

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

      var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
         },
         width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
         height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
         .range([0, width]);

      var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
         .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(xScale)
         .orient("bottom");

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(yScale)
         .orient("left");

      svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .call(yAxis)
         .append("text")
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
         .attr("y", 6)
         .attr("dy", ".71em")
         .style("text-anchor", "end")
         .text("Measurement");

      var lines = svg.append("g").attr("class", "plot").selectAll("line");

      d3.tsv("smidata.tsv", function (error, data) {
         if (error) throw error;
         update(data);
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could use [a gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp). See [this example](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/).

Answer (score 0):

For styling, use [style](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#style) function in every `path` element.

EDIT:

I am sorry; I completely misunderstood your question. I think your best option is to prepare accordingly your data first, so that you can use the API properly. For instance, the following method does the job:

```
var data = [
    {x: 45, variance: 53.4, min: 55, max: 60},
    {x: 46, variance: 52.2, min: 51, max: 60},
    {x: 47, variance: 52.7, min: 52, max: 60},
    {x: 48, variance: 53.1, min: 53, max: 60},
    {x: 49, variance: 49.0, min: 54, max: 60},
    {x: 50, variance: 50.4, min: 55, max: 60},
    {x: 51, variance: 51.1, min: 56, max: 60},
    {x: 52, variance: 52.3, min: 51, max: 60},
    {x: 53, variance: 54.6, min: 52, max: 60},
    {x: 54, variance: 55.1, min: 53, max: 60},
    {x: 55, variance: 51.5, min: 53, max: 60},
    {x: 56, variance: 53.6, min: 54, max: 60},
    {x: 57, variance: 52.3, min: 55, max: 60}
];

var prepareData = function(data){
    var result = [];
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {
        var x1,y1,x2,y2;
        // 0-length line
        if (i == data.length - 1) {
            x1 = x2 = d.x;
            y1 = y2 = d.variance; 
        } else {
            x1 = d.x;
            x2 = data[i+1].x;
            y1 = d.variance;
            y2 = data[i+1].variance;
        }
        result.push({points: [{x: x1, y: y1}, {x: x2, y: y2}], variance: d.variance, min: d.min, max: d.max});
    });
    return result;
}

data = prepareData(data);
```

Next, you have to work with the scales so that they match your interests. From your example, I inferred the following values are fine:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

xExtents = d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.points.map(function(d) { return d.x; }); }))

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(xExtents[0]), d3.max(xExtents[1])])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Finally, drawing all lines is pretty simple:

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var lines = svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data);

lines
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('d', function (d) { return line(d.points); })
    .style('stroke', function(d) { return (d.variance > d.min && d.variance < d.max) ? "black" : "red"; });
```

I have created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarandaf/L93dtou7/3/) trying to recreate such scenario, which I encourage you to do in further questions so that we can see what you have tried so far and understand better what you want to achieve.

Comment: No, I have the same kind of error. I pasted the full code in the question though.

Comment: PeeWee2201 Try finding the line and using the style function it works for sure. Find this example. fiddle.jshell.net/4xZwb/3

Comment: @jarandaf With this edit, there is no error. But the anonymous function to get the stroke is called only once with all data. I want it to be called for each data point.

Comment: @Dileep Thanks for the link, I could figure out how to do it (still very rough though).

Comment: Good to here that dude. Cheers ;)

Comment: @PeeWee2201 I misunderstood you completely. I have updated my answer with a fiddle trying to recreate your scenario (please notice instead of loading your data from an external source, I just created an object with the proper values). I hope it helps.